# Problem with MongoDB's aggregate function, getting erromessage not understanding why

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, non-relational-database

For school assignment, I've got to execute several MongoDB queries regarding specific problems related to Sales and their details. I'm now getting a problem I haven't encountered before, and being completly new to Mongo doesn't help.

I've been using Robo 3t to help me in the task, and I haven't been able to get anywhere, having tried multiple solutions. I also can't seem to find the problem online, hence me asking here.
So, the code is as it follows:

```
db.salesdetails.aggregate(
[   
    {
        $project: {
            month: { $month: "$OrderDate" },
            year: { $year: "$OrderDate" },
            store:{$toInt:"$Store"},
            ReceiptID:1,
            _id:0
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {

            month: 05, 
            year: 2011,
            store:1046

        }
    }
])
```

The expected output would be the Store(an integer, as noted), the month, year and the ID of the Receipt that fall into the specificed timeframe and store.
However, instead of returning it, I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYwnS.png

Once I remove the "store:1046" on the match field, the aggregation is sucessful, and I don't have any idea why it is behaving like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be worth starting with the match pipeline first without converting the store to int then project after filtering

Comment: Problem is, I need the month and year on the match so that I can actually use the query as intended, which is to go check data from that specific time period.

Comment: in plain English, you are trying to retrieve all sales details for a specific store for the given month and year parameters and projecting the selected fields ?

Comment: Exactly, that's it. I'm sorry for my bad semantics...

Comment: I suggest reading up on aggregate. Not sure if you need it at all. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Comment: If using aggregation is not a requirement of your assignment, you should be able to use [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html#op._S_gte) and [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/index.html#lte) to select your date range using the [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#db-collection-find) method, which has the added benefit of being able to use an index to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you use MongoDB date operators (`$month` and `$year` in this case) on a string type.  Do a `db.salesdetails.findOne()` and post the result.  I believe you have a string value in *OrderDate* field instead of a date (`ISODate(...))`  I have verified on both Compass and Robo 3T that your aggregate pipeline work if the data type is correct.